# no pg_hba.conf entry for host. PostgreSQL unable to connect via IP address?

Tags: postgresql, ip

Unable to connect to PostgreSQL via IP.

```
Error Message: no pg_hba.conf entry for host
```

P.S: installation of Adobe Campaign Management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_hba.conf` is configured to allow connections only from the pc the
database is installed on initially.  Only one login account exists by
default after a new installation and that is the postgres account. 
Until you connect to the db the first time using the postgres account
and create new users accounts will you have the option of using your
Owner account.

For connecting from another windows pc other than the one postgres is
running on the default `postgresql.conf` file must be modified before
modifying `pg_hba.conf`.  Within postgresql.conf there is an entry
commented out, `tcpip_socket = false`, uncomment that line and change it
to equal true.
Now you can modify the pg_hba.conf.  Add a new line to that reads the
following:

```
host      all       all         XXX   255.255.255.255  trust
```

XXX = the ip address of the computer that your application is running
on.  If your ip address is say 192.168.123.250 it is ok to enter it in
pg_hba.conf as 192.168.123.0.  The .0 acts a wildcard in case your
computer is assigned a new ip address at a later time (hopefully it will
be in the same range as the original...)

Once the above is done you can reboot the computer to stop and restart
PostgresSQL.

Comment: The computer reboot is not necessary. The reload PostgreSQL server is good enough.

Comment: had the same problem and installed MSSQL instead. thank you for future reference